# How to make web help like Eclipse Help System

Tags: eclipse, web

I like the help system on Eclipse web site (http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp). I am wondering how this is made and what the software tools are behind. We'd like to move our documentation to such a system, if cost allows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation on how to use the Eclipse help system can be found in these articles:

- http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=226
- http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=397

These, and many more resources on Eclipse development can be found here: http://www.eclipse.org/articles

If your documentation is currently on a wiki, you could generate the Eclipse help format from that: http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocumentationGuidelines/CrowdSourcingExample